# Angular Cannot read property of null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, undefined

In a web app I have two box containing some elements. I also have an aside with filters (composed by a selection). At the beginning the filters are all selected, and it works. But when I try a combination which find nothing in the first list but there are some data in the second list, I got an error. This is the when I call the Service in the controller:

```
if(data){ // If i have some response form serve

 var tmp = null;
 var lastName = null;

 angular.forEach(data.people, function(ppl){
 if(ppl.lastName != lastName){
    if (lastName != null){
        $scope.people.push(tmp);
    }
    // Clean the tmp
    tmp = {
           name : null,
           count : 0,
           products : []
     };
     // Update lastName
     lastName = ppl.lastName;
  }
   // Add the actual row in the ob
   tmp.name = lastName;
   tmp.count += ppl.personCount;
   tmp.products.push(ppl);
  });

  // Process lasts elements (if there are some) in the array
  if(tmp.products.length > 0){
    $scope.people.push(tmp);
  }
```

The error is: `Cannot read property 'products' of null`

I've tried to write:  `var tmp = [];` instead of null, but it says `Cannot read property 'products' of undefined`

Comment: Use `if (tmp && tmp.products && tmp.products.length > 0)` for the last verification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `angular.forEach` is giving you a scoping issue. Try the below code instead.

```
if(data && data.people.length > 0){ // If i have some response form serve

 var tmp = {};
 var lastName = null;

 for(var i = 0; i < data.people.length; i++){
     if(ppl.lastName != lastName){
         if (lastName != null){
             $scope.people.push(tmp);
         }
         // Clean the tmp
         tmp = {
            name : null,
            count : 0,
            products : []
         };
         // Update lastName
         lastName = ppl.lastName;
     }
     // Add the actual row in the ob
     tmp.name = lastName;
     tmp.count += ppl.personCount;
     tmp.products.push(ppl);
  };

  // Process lasts elements (if there are some) in the array
  if (tmp && tmp.products && tmp.products.length > 0)
      $scope.people.push(tmp);
  }
}
```